# uncaught reference error in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to build an app with meteor.js. In the `lib` directory, I've got a file collections.js that looks like:

```
var Datum = new Meteor.Collection('datum');

if (Meteor.isServer && Datum.find().count() == 0) {

var datum = [{...}]

    _.each(datum, function(data) {
  Datum.insert(data);
});
}
```

And then in my .js file in the `client` directory looks like:

```
Template.datum.helpers({
  datum: function() {return Datum.find(); }
});
```

When I try to run the app, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Datum is not defined` and a blank page. I can't for the life of me figure out why that's happening. Any suggestions or help? I'm sure it must me be doing something stupid but I just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `var` keyword.

---

All javascript files in Meteor are embedded in the `(function(){...})()` pattern, therefore all variables defined with the `var` keyword are local to the file. If you want to create a global variable, visible to the whole application, do it without the keyword.

So, instead of

```
var Datum = new Meteor.Collection('datum'); // local
```

there should be

```
Datum = new Meteor.Collection('datum'); // global
```

Comment: Is that a Meteor feature or JavaScript one? I mean `var` vs. `no var`